# Cauchy sequence is convergent if it has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that there are several proofs of this on this site and on the internet, however, my doubt is about something very specific. I will write my question first and my proof below.

My doubt is if I can always choose $ X_m = (X_n)_k$ on the step 3 and 4 on the proof below, I am not sure why this makes sense.

**Proof**

I am doing the proof on R for simplicity, but I know that it can be easily generalized for any metric space, feel free to make any comment in terms of metrics/metric spaces.

**Step 1:**  The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy so for any $l$ > 0 exists P $\leq$ m,n such that  $\mid x_n - x_m \mid < l/2 $

**Step 2:**  The subsequence $\{(x_n)_k\}$ is convergent so for any $l$ > 0 exists N $\leq$ n_k such that  $\mid (x_n)_k - x \mid < l/2 $

**Step 3:**  Chose M = max(m,n,n_k) and x_m = $\{(x_n)_k\}$, such that $\mid x_n - (x_n)_k  \mid + \mid (x_n)_k - x \mid$ < l/2 + l/2

**Step 4:**  By the triangle inequality, $\mid x_n - x  \mid$ < l

Comment: To a first approximation more or less none of this makes sense. The very start, "for any $l > 0$ exists $P \leq m,n$ such that  $\mid x_n - x_m \mid < l/2 $ " makes no sense, because you haven't said what $n$ and $m$ are. It's also simply wrong. You've seen the magic words "so for any $l>0$ there exists $P$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<l/2$ for every $n,m>P$." If you take that and scramble the word order at random what results is not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it down in a more structured way. You have the idea, I think, but it needs a better write-up:

So suppose $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $(X,d)$ and we have a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ that converges to some limit $p \in X$.

The claim is that $x_n \to p$ as well. So we start by letting $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

- We apply the Cauchy condition to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and conclude that there exists some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that

$$\forall n,m \ge N: d(x_n, x_m) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

- Now using that $x_{n_k} \to p$ as $k \to \infty$, pick $M \in \Bbb N$ so that

$$\forall k \ge M: d(x_{n_k}, p) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

- Now there exists some $k' \ge M$ so that $n_{k'} > N$ as the subsequence indices are increasing without bound in $\Bbb N$. Now apply the triangle inequality:

$$\forall n \ge N: d(x_n, p) \le d(x_n, x_{n_{k'}}) + d(x_{n_{k'}}, p) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$

where the first $<$ is because of the Cauchy condition (we take $m= n_{k'}$ there) and the second because of the convergence condition.

- As $\varepsilon >0$ was arbitrary, $x_n \to x$ as required.